# IOS 14 Images rendering Issue react native

Tags: ios, react-native, ios14

I am unable to render Images on IOS 14 Simulator

I have tried the following

[issue resolution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428)

But after trying the above code , when I re build the code, changes are  automatically undone, and issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

**It can display the image after adding [super displayLayer:layer]; if _currentFrame is nil
if I understand correctly, _currentFrame should be for animated image, so if it is still image, we can use the UIImage implementation to handle image rendering, not sure if it is a correct fix.
react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m**

```
  if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```